# Flutter, correct way to set it?

Tags: android, flutter

I am having trouble with setting Flutter right.

When I use flutter doctor command everything works perfectly. But when I used `flutter run -v` command I got this error message(on screen down below).

Also when I used flutter create [name of the project] it returned this error message:

> "C:\src\flutter_windows_2.5.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\templates\app_shared\android.tmpl\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png to C:\Users\proch\OneDrive\Plocha\serpent\test\test\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png due to unknown error. The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user."

Please someone help me. I am trying to set it right for the whole weekend.

[This is what happens when I use flutter run -v command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpG0J.png)

Comment: is it possible that this error occurs because you are trying to make a flutter project within a onedrive folder? Does the same happen when making a new project on desktop? If so, maybe delete flutter and reinstall?

Comment: I tried to reinstall Flutter for like 40 times. Same for android studio but it wont work. I will try to make it in the folder which is not one drive located but I dont see any problem in it.

Comment: Yes, this is quite a weird error, if moving outside of OneDrive does not help, could you show every file and folder inside your project structure? Do you get the same error if you download an existing repo and run that instead?

Comment: Okay I tried reinstall flutter for one more time and I moved from OneDrive and the the project was created sucesfully. I havent tried it yet in IDE but I guess it worked. I will let you know when I will reinstall my IDE (just to be sure).